# HighCPU-Power RPS Process

Tags: cisco-catalyst, cpu

By chance no one encountered such a problem, periodically due to the "Power RPS Process" process, the processor is very heavily loaded,accordingly, I constantly receive alerts about a high delay to the switch, I don’t notice any problems with user traffic.

Switch:

```
WS-C2960X-24PS-L          15.2(2)E5             C2960X-UNIVERSALK9-M

 PID Runtime(ms)     Invoked      uSecs   5Sec   1Min   5Min TTY Process

 181  1367570308    34977206      39099 44.46% 25.47% 20.32%   0 Power RPS Proces
```

Unfortunately, I couldn't find anything similar on the Internet.

Comment: Has any answer solved your question? Then please accept it or your question will keep popping up here forever. Please also consider voting for useful answers.

Answer (score 0):

Is there an RPS connected? If so, try if disconnecting or rebooting it changes anything.

Otherwise I'd check for firmware updates. As far as I can see, the current version is 15.2.7E8.

Comment: Yes, the switch is connected to the RPS. I don't see this problem on other switches.
I will do as you advised, if it does not help, then I will update the firmware at the end. I'll let you know if it works, thanks!

Comment: On the same RPS? Then I would try swapping ports or cables to see whether the problem moves to the other switch.

Comment: It looks like this is somehow connected with a certain model, I'm not sure about the firmware yet, I don't see this on the "WS-C2960 + 24TC-L" models. But on the models "WS-C2960X-24PS-L" I see constantly on different RPS.
Apparently it has something to do with POE.

Comment: @ГлебЩеголев That could be a bug - have you tried a firmware update or read the release notes whether your problem has been addressed?

Comment: I'll do that in the next few days, thanks!
I will let you know